# How to make mouseenter, mouseleave toggle in one function

Tags: jquery

I looked around here and found a solution, but I was wondering if there were a way to write simpler code. Basically what I created is a simple fade in, fade out hover effect for an image.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.photos div',function () {
    "use strict";
    $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 800);
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','.photos div',function () {
    "use strict";
    $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 800);
});
```

I know you can put the mouseenter,mouseleave together but I do not know how to structure the toggle function like that. Please let me know how to simplify this.

Comment: `"use strict";` is something you write once at the beginning of your JS file – not in every single function … And if you want to handle these two events with one callback function, then you’ll probably want a way to know which event it was inside the callback function. So go look at the properties of the event object (and make your function take it as the first parameter.)

Comment: It's perfectly legitimate to define `use strict` at a function level if you don't want it to apply elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason you want to achieve this effect with Javacscript? You can achieve exactly what you're after with pure CSS:

```
#an-image {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
}

#an-image:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
}
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/oqqx1z3k/

You can view [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/36uzbndo/30/) to see it combined with the example you gave.

Comment: I like the idea of using straight css but in my case there is a an image that fades in on top of another image. So it's two image both position absolute inside of the same div.

Comment: That doesn't sound like there is any reason why CSS would not work. If you believe there is, post another question describing the real issue.

Comment: I am adding a sample fiddle to what I am trying achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/36uzbndo/29/

Comment: There is nothing there that cannot be done in CSS. See my edit above to see the jsfiddle of your demo working without JS.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't test this but I beleive you could use the .fadetoggle() function which will do what you want.

```
$('.photos div').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function () {

    $(this).find('img.nocolor').togglefade('slow');
});
```

or

```
$('.photos div').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 800);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 800);
    }
})
```

However I'm not a fan of working with toggle and mouseenter and mouseleave simply because those functions work based on mouse movement and not position based on html document.

Answer (score 2):

```
$( '.photos div' ).hover(
  function() {
    // MOUSE ENTER
    $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 800);
  }, function() {
    // MOUSE LEAVE
    $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 800);
  }
);
```

EDIT: selector to bind function is not document, it's '.photos div'

Comment: Need to rethink `hover` on `document` ... only time mouse would leave is in browser toolbar or leaving browser window

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, I just edited the selector :)

Comment: problem will be that OP is likely delegating the event to account for future elements that don't already exist

Comment: OP should clarify. Also I'm thinking the CSS solution posted above could really be the best approach.

Comment: css yes...if op is really looking for hover animations, could be also asking in general for more complex situation

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate using `event.type`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.photos div',function (evt) {
    "use strict";
     var opacity = evt.type === 'mouseenter' ? 0 : 1;
    $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': opacity }, 800);
});
```

Also the `fadeTo()` method is the same as the animation you are using

```
 $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.photos div',function (evt) {
    "use strict";
     var opacity = evt.type === 'mouseenter' ? 0 : 1;
    $(this).find('img.nocolor').stop().fadeTo( 800, opacity);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.type` to achieve this with a single toggle function as follows:

```js
function toggleAnimation(eventName)
{
   "use strict";
  
   $(document).find('img.nocolor').stop().animate({ 'opacity': 
            (eventName == 'mouseenter') ? '0' : '1' }, 800);
}


$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.photos div',function (event) {
     toggleAnimation(event.type);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="photos">
  <div>
<img width="300px" src="http://www.lb.undp.org/content/dam/lebanon/img/AboutLebanon/Lebanon.png" class="nocolor" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for simplifying this for me. Sometimes I work backwards and don't see how simple something can be!